# Ubuntu 14.04: possible port-forwarding issue, OpenVPN closing/blocking ports?

Tags: networking, server, iptables, openvpn, port-forwarding

My server is setup with `eth0` (192.168.1.100) and `wlan0` AP (192.168.5.1).  I set my BT router to forward TCP and UDP ports 8080 and 8443 (http and https ports user-specified in Subsonic server config file) to `eth0`.  The server will also define/register a username.subsonic.org website that makes the Android app connection easier in case the ISP changes the IP address on the front end.  I have disabled `ufw` and have tried disabling the router's firewall and it made no difference.

So, on the local host, I can type the IP address/port of both of my interfaces and it will take me to my login page.  But when I enter the username.subsonic.org address it will default to the wlan0 address.

Even worse, once I connect my OpenVPN, it will resolve the website URL to the forward-facing IP.

Also, the app won't connect using the website or forward-facing URL

Do I have a port-forwarding issue?  I really have no idea where to start eating this elephant, but I'm down for one bite at a time.

```
user@server:~$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan+ -o tun+ -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

--update--
The output of `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` shows that the 8080 and 8443 ports are only being listened to on tcp6, not tcp...

Comment: Bump bump bumpy

Comment: PLease halp????